# Multiple horizontal line chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, horizontal-line

I'm trying to create a horizontal line chart with 5 categories (qualitative variable). The trick is I have multiple horizontal lines (quantitative variable) in each of the 5 categories and I'm unable to plot it in R.

My sample data has the following attributes:

```
slno start  finish
1   0.45    0.52
1   0.52    0.6
1   0.63    0.69
1   0.77    0.9
1   1.55    1.75
1   10.4    12.5
1   2.09    2.35
1   0.52    0.9
2   0.43    0.45
2   0.45    0.51
2   0.52    0.59
3   0.63    0.67
3   0.85    0.88
3   1.57    1.65
4   2.11    2.29
4   0.5     0.68
4   1.36    1.38
4   10.6    11.19
5   11.5    12.51
5   0.43    0.45
5   0.48    0.52
5   0.54    0.57
```

The graph should look something like this:

[image]

This graph is a very rough representation of what I'm after and is by no means representative of the data I've pasted above.

Here's what I've attempted so far.

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=start, y=slno, xend=finish, yend=5), color="blue")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for ?

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = start, xend = finish, y = slno, yend = slno, color = as.factor(slno)), size = 2)
```

[image]